# What is the flow of MVP pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

can anyone give me short & simple code in c# to understand the MVP pattern? please help. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

read this: [What are MVP-Passive View and MVP-Supervising controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381847/what-is-mvp-passive-view-and-mvp-supervising-controller)

and here's C# sample code with good description 
http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/05/25/build-you-own-cab-part-3-the-supervising-controller-pattern/